# How to align the caption text to the right in a bootstrap caroussel?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to align the caption text of a twitter bootstrap caroussel to the right. How can I do so ?

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
        <img src="img/img1.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">
        <div class="carousel-caption right-caption">
            This is the text I want to put on the right.
        </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

try to wrap your text with class text-right.

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
        <img src="img/img1.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">
        <div class="carousel-caption right-caption text-right">
            This is the text I want to put on the right.
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just if I can give some more insight to this:

Adding `text-right` to the `carousel-caption` div will not work, because there is a current text-align CSS style for `carousel-caption`, setting it to center.

This block of CSS appears AFTER the `text-right` class in the Bootstrap style, so adding `text-right` will not override the `carousel-caption` style.

This, in my opinion is wrong, as the `text-left`, `text-center` and `text-right` classes should have `!important` added to them to override anything.

The only way you can change your text alignment is by creating your own CSS style for `carousel-caption`.

```
.carousel-caption {
    text-align: right;
}
```

---

If you still want to add `text-right` as a class, and use that, you'll need to add this to your custom CSS block:

```
.carousel-caption.text-right {
    text-align: right;
}
```